# Combine work days and calendar days for a calculator

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im trying to create a calculator for detention of containers.

Each provider has different rules that have a breakdown between work days and calendar days.

for example:

1. the first 5 working days (excl Saturday and Sunday) are free of cost
2. After that the next 3 calendar days are at a cost of 135
3. After the above, the next 5 calendar days are at a cost of 160
4. After that 180 onward.

is this possible to do in excel? My idea is to have a difference between 2 dates: date of arrival versus date of return. and based on the 4 rules below use "IF" to give me a cost.

what would be a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Consider creating a VBA function that accepts the start/end dates and the name of the provider, and returns a value based on the rules for each provider. I am suggesting using a VBA function rather than worksheet functions using IF as the calculations are certain to change, and it will be easier to maintain this way.

Comment: Hi applecore! could you help me with a sample vba function that I could use? Im not too good on macros but im always willing to learn

Answer (score 0):

HardCoded option:

With Dynamic array formula `SEQUENCE()`

```
=SUM(IF(SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,,A1)<WORKDAY(A1,5),0,IF(SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,,A1)<WORKDAY(A1,5)+3,135,IF(SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,,A1)<WORKDAY(A1,5)+8,160,180))))
```

Older version:

```
=SUM(IF(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1))<WORKDAY(A1,5),0,IF(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1))<WORKDAY(A1,5)+3,135,IF(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1))<WORKDAY(A1,5)+8,160,180))))
```

As an array formula, using Ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Using a lookup table.

Put 0 in the first cell in the lookup table.  The second cell would get the formula `=WORKDAY(A1,5)` the next below: `=F2+3` and the last `=F3+5` and put the corresponding values:

[image]

Then use SUMPRODUCT and LOOKUP:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,,A1),F1:F4,G1:G4))
```

older version:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1)),F1:F4,G1:G4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is a VBA function that accepts three arguments - the start date, the end date, and the name of the carrier, and returns a cost. Only costing for one carrier is included, but it can be expanded for other carriers.

```
Function fContainerCost(dtmStart As Date, dtmEnd As Date, strCarrier As String) As Currency
    Dim lngDays As Long
    Select Case strCarrier
        Case "CarrierA"
            dtmStart = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(dtmStart, 5)
            If dtmStart > dtmEnd Then
                fContainerCost = 0
            Else
                lngDays = DateDiff("d", dtmStart, dtmEnd) + 1 '   need to get the actual days, so get the difference in dates and add 1.
                If lngDays <= 3 Then
                    fContainerCost = fContainerCost + (135 * lngDays)
                Else
                    fContainerCost = fContainerCost + (135 * 3)
                    lngDays = lngDays - 3
                    If lngDays <= 5 Then
                        fContainerCost = fContainerCost + (160 * lngDays)
                    Else
                        fContainerCost = fContainerCost + (160 * 5)
                        lngDays = lngDays - 5
                        fContainerCost = fContainerCost + (180 * lngDays)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Case "CarrierB"

    End Select
End Function
```

To use it, just treat it as a regular Excel function:

```
=fContainerCost(A1,B1,C1)
```

Regards,